# How can you enable PHPMyAdmin foreign key hyperlinking?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have two servers, one is my development VM on my local machine, and another a cloud server- both running the same version of Ubuntu and the same version of PHPMyAdmin.

On my dev VM when browsing a table that contains fields that are foreign keys, it turns those values into hyperlinks that you can click to get quickly to the row in the related table.

Yet the PHPMyAdmin on my cloud instance doesn't do this? I haven't configured them differently, they're practically on the same default configuration pulled from aptitude.

Any idea how I can enable it? `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` seems to contain nothing of relevance to this and I can't find the functionality documented anywhere.

Comment: Maybe shooting in the wrong direction, but what is the table engine? Foreign keys require InnoDB.

Comment: They're both InnoDB, they're the same system just dev/prod environments. Just realised the dev also has an extra 'Designer' tab that produces awesomeish diagrams by the look of it; perhaps linked to that.

Comment: To enable 'designer mode' you have to change some configuration params; of which mine were already set to; and run some SQL to create a database called 'phpmyadmin' with a few tables in it.. this didn't seem to do it though; I'm thinking enabling designer mode will also solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some resources to enable the special "pma" features:

1. http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/#linked-tables
2. http://www.posteet.com/view/545

Basically, you need to create a special phpmyadmin "meta" database, and enable the features in the config file.

Good luck!

Comment: Any chance of getting an updated link to the phpmyadmin documentation?